# Add Platform in Application Registration Portal

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am trying to register a mobile app to the Application Registration Portal but whenever I click the App Platform I get the option of 1. Web  2. Native Application 3. Web API. But I do not see the option for mobile app.

But when I try the native app, two platforms are added. one for Web and the other for Native Application. Why the platform for Web is added.

I am very new to this development.

Because of this whenever I am running the Xamarin.Forms app on iPhone simulator, I am getting the message that "Safari cannot open the page because the address is invalid".

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Thank you Halfer for noticing the word "urgent" in my question. I put it inadvertently. I do not post the questions too often and so do not know the rules too much. I will keep in mind when posting question next time.

Comment: No worries, thanks Sanjay.

Answer (score 0):

Native application is for both the PC's application and the mobile application.

When you choose native application, web application is added because you may need to use a web server as a back-end service for your native app.

I don't think this issue related to your problem with iPhone and Safari.